# SqlDataReader only evaluate a row at a time

Tags: .net, sqldatareader

It appears that under the covers SqlDataReader will actuall grab multiple rows at a time

I have a situation where I need to to grab a single row at a time.
In the SqlDataReader loop I may change, insert, or delete rows using a separate SQLcommand.
The problem I have is that may be a change to data the SqlDataReader has prefetched so I get stale data. 
I don't really need to see the inserts performed in the loop but if I read them it does not break anything.

How do I get SqlDataReader.Read() to actually read a single row at a time from the database?

Comment: How are you changing or deleting rows from a DataReader?

Comment: So if you delete the next row you do not expect it to be read from the  `SqlDataReader`?

Comment: @LarsTech with a SqlCommand. How else would I change a row in .NET?

Comment: @Magnus Correct.  If the row it deleted I don't want to read it and if the row is changed I don't want the stale value(s).  I seems to prefetch like 100 at a time.

Comment: A DataReader isn't running a brand new query every time you call read.  It is just fetching the next row of information based on the cursor position.  I think we need to see some code to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @LarsTech Exactly.  And if the row it prefetches changed then I get stale data.

Comment: The DataReader wasn't designed to do what you are doing.  It was designed to avoid bringing all of the data over the pipe at once, so that it would be more efficient.  You will have to rethink your design.

Comment: What you are seeing is the effects of how a transaction works. The retrieval of the data is done within the scope of a transaction, which means you see a consistent view of the data for the duration of the transaction. Imagine in a banking scenario you are moving money from one account to another. If you read the first account after it has been debited and the second account before it has been credited it looks like you have no money. You probably wouldn't like that very much. You might be able to fiddle with the isolation level so that dirty/phantom reads are allowed.

Comment: @CraigW. Wrong, this is not a transaction thing. SQLDataReader does not take a transaction. If SQLDataReader was holding a transcaction on the read I would not be able to update at all.

Comment: @BLam Wrong, it is totally a transaction thing. Maybe some basic education is in order - read up on ACID and maybe read the relational theorem from cobbs. You violate A and I - two of the SQL transactional pillars.

Comment: @TomTom Yes some education is in order.  This is not a SQL thing nor an ACID thing.  The update/insert/takes takes place.  SQL has the correct data.  There is still some stale data in the SQLdatareader.  This is a SQLdatareader thing only.  If I try and act on the stale data SQL is aware that data has been changed.  There is no ACID violation.

Comment: @Blam there absolutely is an ACID ciolation except when you use MARS on one connection or artificially merge multiple connections to one transaction - otherwise the I part comes in, and the design really really erally is odd.

Comment: As TomTom mentioned, you are incorrect. EVERY operation inside the database is performed in the context of a transaction, whether explicit or implicit. A transaction doesn't necessarily block other operations, it simply ensures that your view of the database is consistent for the duration of the operation.

Comment: @TomTom What part of the update is correct and satisfies ACID is so hard for you to understand?  It is not SQL's problem that SqlDataReader has stale data.

Comment: @CraigW. And that implicit update/insert/delete transaction is complete and satisfies ACID.  The data in SQL is correct.  It is not SQL's problem the SQLDataReader has stale data nor is that a violation of ACID.

Comment: @Blam As others said you won't be able to use SqlDataReader to do what you want. You might have to consider using TSQL cursors.

Comment: @Crono No I think I can.  What I am doing is validating the Read() as the first line.  Since I am just checking one row via a PK that is very efficient.  But I have to agree a cursor might be better.  But I could just inject this into my current design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server puts as many result set rows as possible in network packets and sends them to the client as fast as possible. The packets containing the result set rows are then cached in the network buffers of the client and read by the accessing driver.
It would be very slow to read them one by one and send them to the client.

Comment: So I will take slower for current data.  In oracle you can configure the fetchsize.  I am not giving up on SQLdataReader just yet.

Comment: Well, in SQL Server you can not - so give up. Point is that unless you pull some really funny stuff you are out of luck anyway as your approach goes against anything SQL has ever stood for - you violate ACID conditions, mostly A and I (Atomic and Isolated). YOu also think it is abou READING - it is not. SQL Srver will process as fast as possible.

Comment: @Blam If you can move whatever you are doing into a stored procedure and execute you query using a cursor I think what you are trying to do would be possible.

Comment: I might be able to fool it with sequential access but not going to take the chance.  Since the data has a PK my thought is just to validate each read.  If the row is gone or the row is changed then for what I am doing I know I can skip that row.  I am probable going to accept you answer but let me play around a bit.

Comment: @Blam Possibly, but I doubt it. I think the buffer would be filled with as much data as possible. Only with `sequential access` specified less then a complete row might be buffered and available to the reader, since it is intended to be used for reading blobs as a stream.